# Android Media Player Async Prepare the file

Tags: android

I was looking at the Media Player application found in the Android 2.1 platform samples. I gave a link of the URL for the media file i wanted to play. Now it played fine, but the app gave a "taking too long" warning dialog, meaning too much work was been done on the UI. Is there a better approach to prepare the file async, when streaming from the internet, so as not to bug the UI thread more then needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

PrepareAsync() is performed on another thread (hence the name). I don't think the problem is here.

Comment: Hum, if you are talking about the random media player sample. I made it run with JB as the target of the app and I don't remember having to rewrite a lot of things.
These examples are not always kept up to date though, so there are probably some minor changes to do.
Can you post the problematic code ?

Answer (score 0):

I use Service to for player. It doesn't require UI so you can be sure it's not blocking ui and it's not killed when you leave activity.

Comment: Caution : by default services run on the same thread than Activities, so they absolutely can block the UI.